# Team member distribute .ipa for testing (Ad Hoc distribution)

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

Preconditions:

1. I'm new to iOS (actually Android developer)
2. I don't have an iOS developer account (didn't pay to Apple)
3. I was invited by my client as a team member with approved development signing certificate

The problem:

Client asked me to create and share build with testers (ad hoc distribution) via TestFlights service.

1. How can a developer (team member) do this? What are the steps for this?
2. Should I ask the client to update my role to admin?
3. Does admin have enough rights for ad hoc distribution?
4. What other dragons lives on this weird way?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to export generated archive for Ad Hoc distribution but Xcode fails with the following error:

[image]

Comment: Look this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901269/xcode-attempted-to-locate-or-generate-matching-signing-assets-and-failed-to-do-s

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for the link. Looks like it was possible to generate an ipa as a Team Member. However I've ended up asking my client to upgrade my role to Admin. Anyway your link is still useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at roles in ios dev program:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/

My suggestion is that you should be upgraded to admin, or your customer needs to do a lot of things (like create the app id, provisioning profile, etc....)

Don't know what is the profile of the customer, is it something technical or not, used to ios dev or not, but if he experienced into this he can help you and should provides all the info, if not, then you have to do it by yourself and the only way is to be admin.

The process seems to be complex, especially the first times, but once you get used to it's quite easy...

Also if you plan to be "serious" about ios dev, I suggest you to get a developer account

Comment: Yes I checked the roles several times. However I saw somewhere on SO (can't provide the exact link, sorry) that only agent can distribute apps. I know that it is true for AppStore distribution so I wanted to be sure admin is able to distribute builds for testing (Ad Hoc) so I have a reason to ask the client to upgrade my role.

Comment: Or maybe there is a way for Ad Hoc distribution for member - also on SO I saw a hack with converting app to ipa, so ipa can be sent to other person and he can install it(assuming that the appropreate UDID are under the provisioning profile), however not sure if it will work

Comment: You will be able to generate the app and distribute to the tester list that the admin is able to manage.
In other words, the admin is able to manage the list of people that can install the app, while developer is able to create the ipa and give it the testers

Comment: Ok, looks like I can still remain a member and distribute the app to tested. What is the flow for this? What are the steps for distributing the ipa to tester for member. What should admin provide for this? What my steps as a member should be then? Currently I'm trying to export an archive for AD Hoc distribution in Xcode and it says that I don't have permissions for this. I have only develpment signing certificate. I'll update my question with the screenshot

Comment: Ended up with request to my client to upgrade my role from member to admin. After generating distribution signing certificate and Ad Hoc Distribution profile via Member center I was finally able to generate .ipa for Ad Hoc Distribution. Still don't know if member is allowed to Ad Hoc distribute builds.